# alfresco subsite

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I installed Alfresco Community 4 a few days ago. I'm using Share.

I'm wondering if I can have multiple document libraries in a single site. The thing is that when a create a new site, I have a link to Document library in the top navigation bar. Then, if I go to "customize site", I can add calendar, wiki, etc... to the top navigation bar, but I would like to have a second document library instead of any of this.

The final result would be to have Doc library 1 and Doc library 2 in the top navigation bar.

Then, i guess this is more advanced, but I would like to create a site template, so that when I create a new site, I automatically have a site with 2 document libraries in the top navigation bar.

I know changes can be made to the Share Application and functionality by modifying or creating XML files in the webapp. If someone could point me to the correct steps and files to create or mofify it would be great.

I hope I don't need to install Eclipse,  create and compile a WAR file, etc. as I have never done this.

Also I read that SubSites is not supported in Alfresco Share, but I don't know if a second document library is considered a subsite. Maybe there is some XML file where I can tell Alfresco's site Type template, Instead of creating a site with Document LIbrary, Calendar, Wiki, etc. Just create a site with 2 Document libraries :)

Thanks. Best regards.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt a second documentlibrary is really what you want. What is the business case behind this and why can't it be accomplished with a basic folder hierarchy underneath the documentlibrary ?

Comment: The case is this law company has more than 300 customers, and they have different departments, like social, fiscal, civil, etc. Each customer will have a site in Alfresco, and I want the documentation of the fiscal department in a different document library to be apart from the social; Yes I could create a folder for each department, but it's not as elegant as SharePoint where you can clearly have a subsite for each department and add not only documents, but any department specific content.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can achieve this out of the box or with just configuration. You will need to do a customization. I'm afraid you will have to go and face your unknown java-path :(